# PHP E_NOTICE best practice - Is it bad to check an undefined var for a value?

Tags: php, error-handling, e-notices

With `E_NOTICE` error messages enabled, PHP doesn't like the following code, unless the variables `$mdDialog` and `$mdToast` have already been defined:

```
if ($mdDialog || $mdToast) {
    $ngMaterial = true;
}
```

To avoid `E_NOTICE` error, I must write:

```
if (isset($mdDialog) || isset($mdToast)) {
    $ngMaterial = true;
}
```

The problem is that, with the above code, if I have a `$mdDialog = false;` line somewhere earlier, the statement will be truthy, which is not the idea. To avoid this, I'd have to write:

```
if ((isset($mdDialog) && $mdDialog) || (isset($mdToast) && $mdToast)) {
    $ngMaterial = true;
}
```

And this is sooo much longer and feels excessive, only to avoid the E_NOTICE message.

So, the question is, should I care about these `E_NOTICE` messages? Is there anything bad with checking the value of a variable that may not exist?

Comment: You can use ternary for the assignment. `isset` also can take multiple variables.. or even use `!empty` if you want to see if it has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`empty` can be useful in this case. Like below:

```
if (!empty($mdDialog) || !empty($mdToast)) {
    $ngMaterial = true;
}
```

Read more about [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: True, that works perfectly well, and cleaner than `isset()`,  though the question remains - is best practice to use the `empty()` function to remove any notices, or is the code quicker just by checking directly if the var is truthy, and hiding any notices that are thrown if it's undefined?

Comment: `empty` also checks for isset along with empty values like blank string `''`, `NULL`, `false` etc. So there will be no undefined warning.

Comment: Note the `The following values are considered to be empty` section in the manual though. If any of those values are valid you'll need to use an `||` and the valid value check; or go back to `isset`.

Comment: It's best practice to write code that does not generate notices, whether hidden or not.

Comment: AbraCadaver Why are notices like these bad? What is caused by checking an undefined var?

Comment: @MarcusEdensky You need to use the `@` for notices to be sent.

Comment: @MarcusEdensky Notices *aren't* bad, that's the point -- but if you blindly ignore them, then you'll never see the ones that are actually meaningful. E.g., if you write your code to not generate notices, and then you get a notice about an undefined variable, then you can be pretty sure you have a bug. Maybe you simply have a spelling typo -- which you'd never catch if you disabled notices.

Answer (score 1):

Or if the variable is a string you can also use this:

```
if(strlen($mdDialog) < 1 || strlen($mdToast) < 1){
     $ngMaterial = true;
 }
```

Comment: This will throw a notice when undefined.

Comment: if the variable is undefined it will not execute this code block

Answer (score 0):

You're always better off avoiding generating notices than setting `error_reporting()` to ignore them. That said, in cases like this, it's almost always easier to make sure that the vars are set at the start than it is to check that they're set every place you refer to them. I.e., the var never gets set for the false condition if you do something like this:

```
if (some condition) {
    $flag = true;
}
```

Instead do something like this:

```
if (some condition) {
    $flag = true;
} else {
    $flag = false;
}
```

Or this:

```
$flag = false;
if (some condition) {
    $flag = true;
}
```

Or this:

```
$flag = (some condition) ? true : false;
```

Or this:

```
$flag = (bool) (some condition);
```

Now you don't need `isset()` or `empty()`, and when you get an `E_NOTICE`, it's actually meaningful.